# Excel Exact Function Not Working

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

When I'm trying to use the and(exact()) function on Excel to see if the values match across a range, if my range is across the same row, I'm getting a formula error whereas if my range is across the same column, I'm getting a TRUE/FALSE output, but it's wrong.

Does anyone know why I'm getting the wrong output?

[image: Vertical 1]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: the way you are using the formula it needs to be an array formula. Press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` when exiting cell edit mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer**

It is because this is an array formula. You must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the keyboard after typing this formula rather than just pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

**Long Answer**

Since this is a pretty simple formula, you can actually use alternatives that are not array formulas.

For example instead of:

```
= AND(EXACT(A4:A6,A4))
```

You can do this:

```
= SUMPRODUCT((A4:A6<>A4)+0)=0
```

And instead of:

```
= AND(EXACT(A2:D2,A2))
```

You can do this:

```
= SUMPRODUCT((A2:D2<>A2)+0)=0
```

The formulas have the same final result, but those with `SUMPRODUCT` are not array formulas. (This is in this specific case only. It is possible to have an array formula that contains `SUMPRODUCT`.)

Comment: SUMPRODUCT is still an array type formula, with all the drawbacks, the only difference is that it does not require the Ctrl-Shift-Enter to force into Array mode as it is programmed to do so.

Comment: @ScottCraner Hm, didn't know that. I always wondered why `SUMPRODUCT` was an oddball when it came to arrays. Do you know if there are any other function that are "automatic" array formulas such as this one?

Comment: there are few financial functions as well as aggregate.

Comment: What exactly is that `SUMPRODUCT` formula doing?  I find the `AND(EXACT(A1:A3,A1))` much easier to read... and I don't think it's just taste.  There are a total of three operators (and, exact, array gather) in AND EXACT... and there are five operations in the `SUMPRODUCT` formula.  I'm not an excel expert but if you were to have me read the docs and understand this in an interview, I would probably fail. I upvoted for the control+shift+enter trick.

Comment: @JohnZabroski `SUMPRODUCT` multiplies together corresponding array elements and then adds them together. For example `SUMPRODUCT({a,b},{c,d})` would yield `ac`+`bd`. When `SUMPRODUCT` has only one argument, it is effectively the same as `SUM`, i.e. `SUMPRODUCT({a,b})` would yield `a`+`b`. The difference, as ScottCraner pointed out, is that `SUMPRODUCT` is an "automatic" array formula, i.e. even if you don't explicity do Ctrl+Shift+Enter, it automatically does it for you.